# How to get the first index value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I'm trying to show also the first index item in my card widget but I'm not really sure why it's not showing so I'll really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

I was able to get it from the second TileItem but I'm not sure why it's not displaying the first TileItem.

I tried to change the condition in the listbuilderwidget but still couldn't fix it yet.

```
  Widget listbuilderwidget(Item app, int index, BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        SizedBox(width: index == 0 ? 0 : 10),
        verticalBarSeparator(app.tileItem[index == 0 ? 1 : index].middleText),
        index == 0
            ? infoWidget(app.figures, app.tileItem[index],
                app.tileItem[1].middleText, context)
            : tileWidget(app.tileItem[index], context),
      ],
    );
  }


  Widget infoWidget(
      Figures figures, TileItem item, String text, BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              figures.title,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.h9,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 5),
            Text(
              figures.subtitle,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 13,
                color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
              ),
            ),
            Icon(
              int.parse(text) < 0 ? Icons.trending_down : Icons.trending_up,
              color: int.parse(text) < 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
              size: 26,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget tileWidget(TileItem item, BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: item.topText.characters.length <= 6 ? 65 : null,
            child: Text(
              item.topText,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.h9,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 5),
          Text(
            item.middleText,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 13, color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            child: Icon(
              int.parse(item.middleText) < 0
                  ? Icons.trending_down
                  : Icons.trending_up,
              color: int.parse(item.middleText) < 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
              size: 26,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: why are you doing this?         index == 0
            ? infoWidget(app.figures, app.tileItem[index],
                app.tileItem[1].middleText, context)
            : tileWidget(app.tileItem[index], context), .... index 0 should give you the first item of a list

Comment: hi I'm confused. so what I should be doing?.

Comment: well I wrote an answer but im not sure if this will help, but maybe, so let me know if it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

```
void main() {
  String a = "Hello";
  var fristLatter = a[0];
  print(fristLatter);
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am not sure that I am giving the best answer, but here are some options:

1. Please try titleItem[0]
2. Use one of the following : `.key, .value, .first`